# Invalid Host header when trying to connect reactjs and domain name

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cross-domain, vps

I'm trying to deploy a JS app (back in nodejs, front in reactjs) on a hosting server. I've dockerized everything (back, front and database) and everything works well, I can access my app through the IP address of the server.

Now I'm trying to setup a domain name to point to my app.
I've a `Invalid Host header when` I try to access from domain name (while still working accessing through server's IP address).

I've tried to add a `HOST:mydomain.com` to the .env of my reactjs app but I got this error `Could not find an open port at mydomain.com`

Would love if someone can help me through this :)

Answer (score 0):

Given app works by IP, you can leave config of app as is. Do not add `HOST` or any other config.

IP to name mapping is done using [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). So made DNS registration in DNS zone like this

```
mydomain.com A <IP address of app>
```

Where `A` is DNS entry type. Or made request to provider to register `A` entry type for you.

For testing purposes you may do mapping on any Windows PS using hosts file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` where mapping is done by

```
<IP address of app> mydomain.com
```

`hosts` works on one PC only.

After adding to `hosts` or to `DNS` try `ping mydomain.com` to make sure that name is resolved to correct IP address.

Mapping on web server is done when one web server hosts several different sites on one IP. But when you use Docker it's best to have one Docker container for one service.